# Adding images to firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am able to get uID of current user in Firebase.

i am saving name and url of the image in firebase database.

I want to save all the image url and name of the image of current user under only 1 node that is its uID.

```
fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
    {
        //Do what you want with the url
        Upload upload = new Upload(filename,
                fileURL);
        mDatabaseRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(upload);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to make a list under a certain node, call `push()` to generate a unique location. So in your case that'd be:

```
mDatabaseRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).push().setValue(upload);
```

Comment: Can you please also help me with how to retrieve that image?
I am getting null values!

Comment: Hey Test. That seems to be a separate problem, so I'd recommend posting it as a new question. If you post a similar reproduction as you did here, you'll have the best chance that someone can help with that problem too.